# Using AngularJS with Processwire CMS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, content-management-system, url-routing

So I'm just getting started with using Processwire(PW) and I really like it so far. I've also recently started using AngularJS and loving it. Now I'm trying to setup angular routing to work with PW but not having much luck. I've google around etc and tried following the following post

[https://processwire.com/talk/topic/6281-angularjs-routing-with-processwire/?hl=%2Bangular+%2Brouting][1]

but still can't get it to work.

I have a simple site setup for a portfolio, `Home/About/Work/Contact`

I would love to have angular route all the other pages into the homepage. At the moment it just goes to the no-found URL.

If anyone could give me some tips that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial might be of use to you:
https://processwire.com/talk/topic/8420-processwire-angularjs/